# После отключения RDP от ubuntu xfce, процесс gui рабочего стола паузится из-за чего не может работать puppeteer, который управляет chrome с головой

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, rdp, sleep, xfce

Есть виртуальный сервер с `ubuntu` на нее установлена `xfce` оболочка, подключение по rdp.

На сервере работает `puppeteer`, который управляет рабочим браузером в режиме дебага - `chrome`, т.е. браузер с головой. Пока `rdp` подключен и открыт - все работает корректно, но стоит только свернуть его и не трогать или отключится от `rdp` - `puppeteer`  и `chrome`падают в паузу, при открытии и совершении действий они оживают.

Насколько понял, чтобы работал `puppeteer` и `chrome` с головой, нужно, чтобы работал графический интерфейс рабочего стола , а когда он паузится из - за того что `rdp` отключен, то и с ним в паузу ( сон ) уходят и `puppeteer` и chrome.

Чтобы это решить я сделал еще один сервер(второй), на который установил `remmina` и там поднял `RDP` до первого сервера, чтобы никогда не отключать `RDP`, но все равно, когда я закрываю `rdp` ко второму серверу происходит тоже самое - `puppeteer` и `chrome` падают в паузу. Видимо из - за того, что второй сервер после отключения `RDP` также паузит рабочий стол что тянет за собой паузу по `RDP`.

Вот и вопрос, что делать чтобы при отключении `RDP`, `gui` рабочего стола удаленного сервера не спал. Правила уходить в сон я везде отключил на серверах.

Быть может есть какой сценарий `SH`, чтобы не давать выходить на паузу `gui` рабочего стола? Удаленный `windows`- сервер вел себя также.